# How to explain this GPU computation?

Tags: image-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I am working on implementing an image processing kernel in 2D on my GPU using OpenCL. I am getting very puzzling results from my GPU. The code uses a 2X2 stencil and computes the average of each input sample in the stencil and adds the computed average to each sample in the output image that lies within the stencil.

Here is the code for the CPU:

```
for(int i2 = 1; i2 < n1; ++i2) {
  for(int i1 = 1; i1 < n2; ++i1) {
    r00 = h_r[i2  ][i1  ];
    r01 = h_r[i2  ][i1-1];
    r10 = h_r[i2-1][i1  ];
    r11 = h_r[i2-1][i1-1];
    rs = 0.25f*(r00+r01+r10+r11);
    s[i2  ][i1  ] += rs;
    s[i2  ][i1-1] += rs;
    s[i2-1][i1  ] += rs;
    s[i2-1][i1-1] += rs;
  }    
}
```

Using

```
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
```

as the input image, I get the following output image after applying this kernel:

```
2 4 4 2
4 8 8 4
4 8 8 4
2 4 4 2
```

In my OpenCL implementation, I have the following kernel:

```
_kernel void soSmoothingNew(__global const float* restrict d_r,
                            __global float* restrict d_s,  
                            int n1, 
                            int n2,)
{
  int g1 = get_global_id(0);
  int g0 = get_global_id(1);

  int i1 = g1+1; 
  int i2 = g0+1; 

  if (i1 >= n2) return;
  if (i2 >= n1) return;

  float r00, r01, r10, r11, rs;
  r01 = d_r[i2*n2+(i1-1)];
  r10 = d_r[(i2-1)*n2 + i1];
  r11 = d_r[(i2-1)*n2 + (i1-1)];
  rs = 0.25f*(r00+r01+r10+r11);
  d_s[i2*n2 + i1] += rs;
  d_s[i2*n2 + (i1-1)] += rs;
  d_s[(i2-1)*n2 + i1] += rs;
  d_s[(i2-1)*n2 + (i1-1)] += rs;

}
```

And the resulting output is:

```
2 2 2 2 
4 6 6 4 
4 6 6 4 
2 4 4 2
```

I am executing the kernel from the host with the following code:

```
size_t local_group_size[2] = {4,4};
size_t global_group_size_block[2] = {ceil((n1/local_group_size[0]) + 1) * local_group_size[0],
  ceil((n2/local_group_size[1]) + 1) * local_group_size[1]}; 

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, 2, NULL, global_group_size_block, local_group_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

For the sake of brevity, I am omitting the `clSetKernelArg`, `clCreateBuffer` and other OpenCL calls.  Note that I also have another kernel that zeros the output `d_s` array on the GPU before executing this kernel.

I am having a difficult time understanding how the threads on the GPU are operating to arrive at this result. Any insight on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are running into race condition when multiple threads write to the same location in global memory.

Comment: @void_ptr Thank you for your response. I have been told that if I compute the even and odd indexed rows (or columns) independently that my kernel can compute correctly. Might you be able to explain how I can do this and why this would work?

Comment: A common pattern is to read multiple locations but only write one location in each thread. You may want to investigate whether your algorithm can be redesigned like that. If not, you need to serialize memory updates, which is plusungood from performance standpoint. Either way, utilizing shared memory is a viable optimization (not before you sort out correctness issues, of course).

Comment: Are you always working with a 4x4 total input size, or does this have to scale up to larger images?

Comment: @mfa No, my plan is to scale up to images much larger in size.

Comment: ok. do you have maximum image dimensions in mind, or arbitrarily large?

Comment: @mfa Arbitrarily large. As long as they can fit into 2GB of RAM on my GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As void_ptr mentioned, your problem is definitely a race condition when writing back the output. A simple way to get around this is to have each work item responsible for fully computing its output pixel. Your algorithm can also be simplified in the process.

Each pixel lies within four 2x2 boxes of pixels, making up a 3x3 region of the image.

```
O O O
O X O  X is the one we want to compute with a work item.
O O O
```

The 2x2 regions can be called As, Bs, Cs, and Ds:

```
A A O  O B B  O O O  O O O
A A O  O B B  C C O  O D D
O O O  O O O  C C O  O D D
```

You may have noticed that when using your original algorithm, the X pixel is part of 4 separate averages. The resulting pixel contains exactly 1.0f * X. Each of the surrounding pixels can be weighed in a similar manner and added to the final output value using this mask:

```
0.25  0.50  0.25
0.50  1.00  0.50
0.25  0.50  0.25
```

These values help arrive at the kernel below.

```
_kernel void soSmoothing(__global const float* restrict d_r, __global float* restrict d_s, int n1, int n2)
{
    //(idX,idY) represents the position to compute and write to d_s
    int idX = get_global_id(0);
    int idY = get_global_id(1);

    //using zero-base indices  
    if(idX >= n1) return;
    if(idY >= n2) return;

    float outValue = 0.0f;

    if(idX > 0){
        outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX-1 + idY*n1]  + 0.25 * d_r[idX + idY*n1];
        if (idY > 0){
            outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX-1 + (idY-1)*n1];
        }
        if (idY < (n2-1)){
            outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX-1 + (idY+1)*n1];
        }
    }

    if(idX < (n1-1)){
        outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX+1 + idY*n1] + 0.25 * d_r[idX + idY*n1];
        if (idY > 0){
            outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX+1 + (idY-1)*n1];
        }
        if (idY < (n2-1)){
            outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX+1 + (idY+1)*n1];
        }
    }

    if (idY > 0){
        outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX + (idY-1)*n1] + 0.25 * d_r[idX + idY*n1];
    }
    if (idY < (n2-1)){
        outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX + (idY+1)*n1] + 0.25 * d_r[idX + idY*n1];
    }

    d_s[idX + idY*n1] = outValue;
}
```

This is by no means the fastest way to compute your output, but It will get you the correct result. The problem of race-condition-writes to global memory has been addressed by only writing once to each element of the output.

**Lots of room for improvement**

1. The big reason why it is not optimal is that each pixel will be read an average of 9 times -- once by every work item around it, and once for its own work item. I can post an update to address this issue if you are stuck on this.
2. A second way to make this run faster is to avoid the condition checking. You can do this by adding a 1 pixel black border around the input, and adjust the coordinate offsets with a +1 in in the x and y axes. I did the offset in the form of '+n1+1' below.

The checks can be avoided because you know that the coordinates will fall in range on the input image. The rest of the kernel stays the same.

```
float outValue = d_r[idX + idY*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX-1 + idY*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX-1 + (idY-1)*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX-1 + (idY+1)*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX+1 + idY*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX+1 + (idY-1)*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.25f * d_r[idX+1 + (idY+1)*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX + (idY-1)*n1 + n1+1];
outValue += 0.50f * d_r[idX + (idY+1)*n1 + n1+1];
```

Comment: Edited the kernel to handle edges correctly. I think this should work properly now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response. Thank you for your help. Your modifications make a lot of sense. I was told by someone that the even and odd rows (or columns) can be computed completely independently. I think this would also help in removing the if statements would it not? Might you know how to create a kernel that takes advantage of that? Thanks again

Comment: Sure. I will post a separate answer with the rows/columns method

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "rows and columns" method you were asking about. The idea is to process non-overlapping areas of the output image at the same time.

[image: Work items groups into columns]

The 16x16 pixel example I use can be extended to any image size. each black box represents a pixel. The different shades of blue are only use to differentiate the work items' area to compute.

If you divide the image into two-pixel-wide columns, you can process each column in a separate thread. This prevents global write collisions between the columns. Repeat with the odd-numbered columns -- ie dx=1 to compute the 2x2 groupings overlapping the columns as the second image shows. This method only prevents write collisions in the horizontal direction, but you still need to account for the rows.

[image: Making sure to separate the work items row-wise]

To avoid the write collisions within the columns, you need to further divide the columns into rows as shown in the above image. Let's have one work item compute a single 2x2 output to keep the kernel as simple as possible. The rows are computed in two stages too -- dy=0, and dy=1. In total, this is a four-step algorithm, where each step can be called 'embarrassingly parallel'. These steps can be referred to by their position offsets from the origin: (dx,dy) = A(0,0), B(1,0), C(1,0), and D(1,1). Notice that the groups not necessarily use the same number of work items depending on whether the final row/column is large enough for the calculation.

[image: Example work item geography]

An illustration showing what two example work items are responsible for during a kernel call. The "rows and columns" have essentially become "4 checker boards". Below is the kernel which will compute the average of a 2x2 group of pixels and add the global buffer. As long as each group A, B, C, and D is executed on it's own, there is no need to check for global write collisions.

```
_kernel void soSmoothing(__global const float* restrict inData, __global float* restrict outData, int width, int height, int dx, int dy)
{
    //(idX,idY) represents the position to compute and write to outData
    int idX = get_global_id(0);
    int idY = get_global_id(1);

    //(pixelX, pixelY) is the top-left corner of the square to compute
    int pixelX = idX *2 +dx;
    int pixelY = idY *2 +dy;

    if(pixelX > (width-2)) return;
    if(pixelY > (height-2)) return;

    //do the math and add to the corresponding addresses in outData
    int topLeftAddress = pixelX + pixelY * width;
    float avg = 0.25f * (inData[topLeftAddress] + inData[topLeftAddress +1] + inData[topLeftAddress + width] + inData[topLeftAddress + width +1]);
    outData[topLeftAddress] = outData[topLeftAddress] + avg;
    outData[topLeftAddress +1] = outData[topLeftAddress +1] + avg;
    outData[topLeftAddress +width] = outData[topLeftAddress +width] + avg;
    outData[topLeftAddress +width +1] = outData[topLeftAddress +width +1] + avg;
}
```

**Steps for the host code:**

1) set up the command queue as blocking

2) set up buffers: 1x input, 1x output

3) copy input buffer to device, initialize output to 0s on device

4a) enqueue the kernel with dx=0, dy=0

4b) enqueue the kernel with dx=1, dy=0

4c) enqueue the kernel with dx=0, dy=1

4d) enqueue the kernel with dx=1, dy=1

5) read the output buffer back to the host

Notice that the output does not need to be copied to the host until all kernel executions are finished.

**Advantages:**

- The same input for all 4 kernel runs means that you can very easily run this on up to 4 separate devices, and sum their outputs on the host. Maybe try running 1 kernel on a cpu, and 3 on a gpu. You can also break up the kernel to process smaller regions of the image, and have as many opencl devices participating as you want. The overhead of the transfers would end up being a major bottleneck, so this might not be worth the effort.
- Simple kernel, easily debugged.
- Kernels are 'chained' so that they add to the previous output. Can be run in any order.
- Kernel (+host code) can be easily expanded to support 3x3 or other cell dimensions.

**Disadvantages:**

- Input image is read 4x
- Output pixels are written 4x
- Each work item only computes 4 pixels at a time. Computing a larger area can be faster, but with greater code complexity.

There you go. Please let me know how this works out for you, and if I need to make any corrections.